# cmd delete all folders except last 5

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

im looking for help with a batch code that can help me to delete every folder except the last 5 orderdered by name ASC.
i have something like this:

> - Folder 1
> - Folder 2
> - Folder 3
> - Folder 4
> - Folder 5
> - Folder 6
> - Folder 7
> - Folder 8
> - Folder 9
> - Folder 10

And i want it to end up like this

> - Folder 1 [Deleted]
> - Folder 2 [Deleted]
> - Folder 3 [Deleted]
> - Folder 4 [Deleted]
> - Folder 5 [Deleted]
> - Folder 6
> - Folder 7
> - Folder 8
> - Folder 9
> - Folder 10

hope you can help me, and thank you in advance

Comment: At the cmd prompt `folder 1` and `folder 10` will be next to each other.  Are the folders really numbered?

Comment: not specifically numbered like in the example, but every folder has the date (YYYY/MM/DD) as the folder name

Comment: Folder names can't have a / in them.  This task may be easily done or require more code - it really does help to give actual details.

Comment: sorry, i ment YYYY-MM-DD (2014-07-22)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should keep the 5 newest folders.

It will only echo the rd commands to the console and if they are right then you can remove the `echo`

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=5 delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /o-d /ad') do echo rd /s /q "%%a"
pause
```